# Is it connected to Hibernate or not?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, crud

Lately I found an example of [Spring Boot CRUD](https://github.com/Zianwar/springboot-crud-demo). In the read me there is written :

> This project is based on the Spring Boot project and uses these
>   packages :
>
> - Maven
> - Spring Core
> - Spring Data (Hibernate & MySQL)
> - Spring MVC (Tomcat)
> - Thymleaf

In the source code I do not see anything that would look like this app is somehow connected to the hibernate. Could you help me to solve this little problem? And if it is not connected to the Hibernate how can I connect `CRUD` like that to the Hibernate?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example you've provided you're using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` which already contains predefined hibernate dependencies (see [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa)).

How to work with SQL databases described in [documentation section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html).

Basically you configure hibernate using `application.properties` using following prefix:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.*
```

Answer (score 0):

for Spring boot with hibernate you can follow bellow link :-

https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples

you have to configure hibernate property and datasource property for database connection... but for example i can share some code for Spring hibernate and JPA but Spring boot with hibernate you can follow link:-

```
<bean id="hibernateJpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.amstech.mayal.entity" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="hibernateJpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${database.jdbc.driver.class}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.url" value="${database.jdbc.url}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.username" value="${database.user}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.password" value="${database.password}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
            <entry key="show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.is-lazy"
                value="true" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the Spring Boot Data section of the main documentation.  There is a lot less configuration that is needed and you can do it fluently and leave the xml behind.  JPA + Hibernate is Spring data have become highly interlinked in boot.

Comment: I am sorry but I think that i have not undertood your post. Where is less configuration? In this project which I linked in the question? And what does it mean that I can leave the xml behind? I am sorry but I new new to Spring and I still learning :)

Comment: You do not need to declare using transaction manager.  Look at this link, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways in which spring boot interact with hibernate. In the example you shared it is picking up the db properties from application.properties file and setting up the configuration. Rest of the things it will pick from the dependency provide in pom.xml.

Yes, it is connected with the hibernate. Things you need to do apart from setting up the project is to setting up a database with some username and password. And creating a db schema.Rest of the things will be done by spring boot. Make sure your db username password matches with the application file properties.

Comment: I got only one more question - in the pom.xml file in the project i linked above there are no hibernate dependencies. They are no required? Are spring JPA dependencies enough?

Comment: And I do not have to config dataSource ot TransactionManager or other things like that?